# Class Library(.Net Core) VS Class Library(Portable for iOS,Android and Windows)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, asp.net-core, class-library

I want to develop an API using ASP.NET core web api, the solution contains 3 projects of type class library and 1 projects of type Web api (For Separation of Concern), My API should be consumable from xamarin and angular.
What type of class library should I use :
Class Library(.Net Core) OR Class Library(Portable for iOS,Android and Windows)
I'am using vs 2015 update 3
[Class Library Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWN9G.png)

Comment: You should be using .NET Standard Libraries.

Comment: @JonDouglas Thank you

Comment: You should also use VS 2017. Say goodbye to VS 2015 if you want to target .NET Standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking as mentioned in the comments NetStandard is the way to go if you're trying to share between an AspNetCore project and a Xamarin Project.

The defacto standard of new projects is NetStandard1.4 which while perfectly consumable by Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android, is not going to be consumable by a PCL in your project. In order to share code between the API and a PCL for Xamarin you will need to change the NetStandard version based on what PCL Profile you're using. You can find more information in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) from Microsoft, but here is the key:

- Profile 78 & Profile 259 - need NetStandard1.0
- Profile 111 - can use NetStandard1.0 or NetStandard1.1